# Пулинг опросов в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Я сделал подобие мута, которое удаляет сообщение от нежеланного пользователя, но у меня не получается регистрировать создание опросов от пользователя и удалять соответственно. Есть ли какой-то способ это сделать?

Вот код получения сообщения от пользователя:

```python
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['audio', 'document', 'photo', 'sticker', 'video', 'voice', 'question', 'options', 'all', 'pool'])
def repeat_all_messagess(message):
    try:
        with open("km.txt", "r") as f:
            h = f.read().split()
            mute = h[1]
    except:
        pass

    if message.from_user.id == int(mute):
        with open("km.txt", "r") as f:
            h = f.read().split()
            pn = h[0]
            g = h[2]
            gg = h[3]
        g = g.split('-')
        gg = gg.split(':')
        d1 = datetime.datetime(int(g[2]), int(g[1]), int(g[0]), int(gg[0]), int(gg[1]))
        if pn == '1' and (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours = 3)) < d1:
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Comment: У вас там `pool`, а разве не `poll` должно быть?

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо вам большое помогло

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Сами оформите ответ, вдруг это кому-то поможет, кто тоже такую досадную опечатку сделал )

Answer (score 2):

Что бы ваш handler видел опросы надо в content_types=[] добавить 'poll'

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['poll'])
```

По ошибке в `content_types` был добавлено **'pool'**, а не **'poll'**